# Sum values when filtered and don't sum when unfiltered

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this DAX formula and cannot seem to get it to work for the first condition. When person 1 and person 2 are filtered it should return a total sum for those two people. Instead - 0 is returned. How is my logic flawed here?

```
sum_filter = 
VAR selected = VALUES(table1[people])
VAR excluded = {"person1","person2"}
IF(
   ISEMPTY(EXCEPT(selected, excluded)),
   "TGT: $" & FORMAT(SUM(table1[value]),"#,##0"),
   "TGT: $" & FORMAT(SUM(table1[value]) - CALCULATE (SUM(table1[value]), table1[people] IN excluded),"#,##0")
)
```

Example output:
If person 1 and 2 are filtered (I want these to sum when they are filtered)

```
people    value
person1   1
person2   2
total     3
```

If person 1,2, and now 3 are filtered - only person 3 gets summed

```
people    value
person1   1
person2   2
person3   5
total     5
```

In my real scenario I need to sum if any of persons 1-5 are filtered. So if person 1 is filtered it sums, if persons 2-3 are filtered it sums them, if all persons 1-5 are filtered it sums them - but as soon someone outside of persons 1-5 are added to the filter - it excludes persons 1-5 and you would only get the the sum of persons 6+

In the above - I see the values for person 1 and person 2 in tabular form when using the table visual. But total returned in totals row is 0. This would be the same if I was condensing the value to a single card.

When I filter other persons outside of 1 and 2, it returns the correct value of any other persons minus person 1 and 2 values. But again, with just person 1 and 2 filtered - the value returned is 0 when they have values to sum. It looks like `SUM(SELECTEDVALUE(table1[value]))` is failing. What can I do here, thank you!

Comment: Can you add a few rows' worth of sample data together with expected results for various combinations of people selected in the slicer?

Comment: updated original with some edits for example and a change made to original code based on below example - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve with:

```
sum_filter = 
IF(
   ISFILTERED(table1[people]) && FIRSTNONBLANK(table1[people], 1) IN {"person1","person2"},
   "MTD: " & FORMAT(SUM(table1[value]),"#,##0"),
   "MTD: " & FORMAT(SUM(table1[value]) - SUMX(FILTER(table1, [person] IN {"person1","person2"}),tabl1[value2]),"#,##0")
)
```

It seems that `FIRSTNONBLANK()` makes the summing certain people when filtered and excluding certain people when group 1 filter people are mixed with group 2 filter people. I.e., summing happens with all of group 1 people are filtered, summing on only group 1 people happens only to that group when all of group 1 and 2 are filtered, and when anyone in group 2 is filtered with group 1 unfiltered, then group 2 is summed.

It looks like using `FIRSTNONBLANK()` helps isolate a single value of the list as the first detected value of the list. It also looks like it can break if the first non blank is in fact the first item in the list to sum all if condition 1 is met. If that is true, condition 1 triggers regardless.

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of things going wrong here. First off, you should learn about filter context, which is one of the most fundamental concepts in DAX, and your lack of understanding of it is part of what's causing you problems.

Additionally, you should read the documentation for SELECTEDVALUE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) where you'll find that it *“Returns the value when the context for columnName has been filtered down to one distinct value only. Otherwise returns alternateResult.”*

In your example, when you're on the individual rows in the table visual your filter context has a single value for table1[people], so SELECTEDVALUE 'works' and returns that value and compares it to your list - if the value is person 1 or person 2 it goes to the 'true' path of your IF statement and calculates the sum of that persons value, otherwise it goes to the 'false' path.

However on the total rows (where you've got at least 2 people selected) you're not "*filtered down to one distinct value only*" but rather you've got all the values you're currently filtered to. So SELECTEDVALUE(table1[people]) returns a blank, which obviously isn't in your list, so your IF statement goes to the false path.

Here it gets to `SUM(table1[value]) - SUMX(FILTER(table1, [people] IN {"person1","person2"}), table1[value])` and this is where filter context really kicks in. When your filter context on table1[people] is person 1 and person 2 then

`SUM(table1[value])` and
`SUMX(FILTER(table1, [people] IN {"person1","person2"}), table1[value])` both return the same value, so subtracting a number from itself leaves you with zero, which is what you're seeing on the total row.

I would suggest you use something like

```
sum_filter = 
VAR Selected = VALUES(table1[people])  //List of the people values in the filter context 
VAR Excluded = {"person 1", "person 2"} 
RETURN 
IF(
    //checks if the selected values and the 'excluded' list match
    ISEMPTY (EXCEPT (Selected,Excluded)), 
    //if so, do the sum of the selected values
    SUM(table1[value]),
    //otherwise take the sum of the selected values and subtract the sum of hte excluded values
    SUM(table1[value]) - CALCULATE (SUM(table1[value]),table1[people] IN Excluded) 
)
```

Comment: Hello - very enlightening here after reading up on `selectedvalue` thank you! I plugged your style into my situation and am getting an error that syntax for `IF` is incorrect. I updated my original post to reflect the new structure. Thank you!